# Tag helpers seem to interfere with traditional Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tag-helpers

Applying traditional Razor syntax to a `textarea` with a `asp-for` tag applied to it (and a `RequiredAttribute` applied in the view model) seems to interfere with each other.

```
@{ string disabled = "disabled"; }
<textarea asp-for="Motivation" class="form-control" rows="3" @disabled></textarea>
```

The `disabled` attribute is not applied.

```
<textarea
    class="form-control" rows="3"
    data-val="true" data-val-required="..."
    id="Motivation" name="Motivation" placeholder="...">
</textarea>
```

I can understand something must be going wrong (or is unsupported) since `asp-for` needs to be rewritten to the matching attributes derived from the view model.

My main questions are:

1. Is this documented/expected behavior?
2. What is the 'ASP.NET' way of going about similar modifications to the HTML output?

Comment: I have not tried, but I would expect that you need to follow the `attr="value"` approach. So something like `disabled="@disabled"`.

Comment: @PeterB Interestingly, that does work! Furthermore, the [non-minimized version is required in XHTML it seems](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp). However, I do not believe `disabled=""` or `disabled="enabled"` is valid, so it does not resolve this issue.

Comment: When `@disabled` instead is set to `disabled=\"disabled\"` the whole attribute is omitted again.

Answer (score 0):

I am only just starting out with ASP.NET, so am uncertain as to the first question: *"Is this documented/expected behavior?"* This is thus only a partial answer and I am looking for more information regarding the first question.

However, to answer the second question, one possibility seems to rely on (older?<sup>1</sup>) HTML helpers which offer more flexibility:

```
@{ string disabled = "disabled"; }
@Html.TextAreaFor(
    m => m.Motivation,
    new { @class = "form-control", rows = 3, disabled = disabled } )
```

The second parameters are additional attributes which are applied to the output of the `textarea`.

Furthermore, it should also be noted that in XHTML [attribute minimization is forbidden](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp).

> In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the disabled
>   attribute must be defined as `<input disabled="disabled" />`.

<sup>1</sup> I can't seem to find official documentation on this.